# Firebase FCM for windows

Tags: windows, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a good way to add Firebase server2client FCM messaging to my WPF .net windows app?
We already have it sending GUI-less data messages to our Android/iOS clients, and I would like to recycle the backend integration.

I saw that there is a C++ library, but no mention of anyone using it on Windows.
And I saw that someone put together a hack where they ran the web version inside a .Net app.

But I didn't see any testimonials about using firebase in windows. I don't want to use unofficial solutions which might lose support when a new version is released...

Is there an official way to use FCM in my windows app?

Comment: As @Doug said it's not possible at this moment. C++ can be used from android thats why you saw it in the firebase docs. Why don't you create a notification system with sockets by yourself?

Comment: As stated above: I would like to recycle the backend integration.
Message queues aren't just about pushing packets, there is a whole swath of issues if you want to pull them off at a cloud scale. Ranging from plain IT (scaling,firewalls, opsec, etc..) to coding (authentication models, integration, etc...) . That work has allready been done on firebase. I don't want to repeat it on something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.  FCM is designed for web and mobile (Android, iOS) applications.