# Firebase messaging to a Windows C++ desktop application

Tags: c++, windows, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, desktop

I am trying to configure the firebase SDK to allow messaging to a C++ application on Windows. There is an example online at gitbub. (firebase/quickstart-cpp\messaging/testapp/src/desktop). I configured a Unity app on the firebase console and selected an 'Android' flavour (not sure id this is correct app type, but there is no desktop variant). In any case, the generated google-service.json file loads and configures the firebase application object. However, I don't receive a token in the startup.

Is this the correct process? Would it matter if I configured the desktop application as an Android app explicitly.

Thanks,

Stan

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the 'Android' flavour plays into it, but I it is not possible to receive FCM messages on a native Windows application. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507588/how-to-receive-push-notifications-from-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926125/firebase-fcm-for-windows

Comment: Hi Frank. There are examples in the firebase C++ SDK that are for WIndows desktop. Why would these be here if there is no support for the flow? The 'Android' flavour is selected when you choose Unity. It seems you make it appear as if it's either an Android or iOS application.

Comment: FCM can only deliver messages to native Android and iOS apps, and to web apps (on desktop, Android, and since recently also iOS). It cannot deliver messages to clients on other platforms (as far as I know). I looked in the repo you mentioned, but couldn't really figure out what that code was for.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks. The Unity app type is supposed to support Unity apps which run on many platforms - Windows being one. When you select a UNity App, it ask whether you want it to 'appear' as an Android or iOS app, so I am guessing it's immaterial which you choose. I admit, I don't actually have Unity installed, but it seemed to me that this was close to a desktop situation. There are a few other combinations I need to try, so I'll post back if one works. The application I compiled and linked is a standalone Windows app and it's from the Firebase tree. It should be there for a reason.

Comment: I recommend doing some tests in that case, but I'd be **very** surprised if an app can receive FCM messages on anything but native iOS & Android apps, or web apps.

Comment: i Frank. Figured it out. It''s only in beta form on Windows (same for MacOS and Linux). The libraries are their only in stb form. The purpose is to provide a means of dvelopment and testing up to a point on a desktop platform. The documations is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android&hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*1wzbdy1*_ga*MTg4MzQ4MDQ5MS4xNjkzOTYwNzk5*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY5NDIzMDcwOC4xMS4xLjE2OTQyMzY5NjAuMC4wLjA.#add-sdks.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's correct. But even if it'd come out of beta, I don't expect that Windows apps will be able to receive FCM messages in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that messaging support is only a stub and is left in place to allow development/testing on a desktop platform. However, I asked support directly and they said it's neither excluded nor planned, so I raised a request/suggestion.

In the meantime, I have moved to Amazon SNS messaging. They have a very mature C++ SDK and it compiles and is functional on everything.